# How to debug ImportEror "No Module named ..."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework. When I try to go to the swagger docs page, 
I am getting 
ImportError: No module named drf_compound_fields

```
from  serializers.py where I try to import the following

from drf_compound_fields.fields import ListField
```

I have drf-compound-field 0.2.2 in my virtualenv and I ran pip list command to make sure that it is installed.

Here is what I get from manage.py shell

```
 Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)   
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from drf_compound_fields.fields import ListField
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named drf_compound_fields.fields
>>>
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Did you add it to your installed_apps in your settings.py?

Comment: I did not. drf_compound_fields documentation did not ask anything to be added to settings.py. I just tried it after seeing your comment It gives me ImportError: No module named drf-compound-fields at startup.

Comment: Are you sure you ran pip list and django application with the same virtualenv?

Comment: yes I ran it in the same virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drf-compound-fields` was installed under the same virtualenv where the django server was being run from. 
Apparently, it needs to be installed at the system level and not necessarily at the virtualenv level.

Follow these steps to install `drf-compound-fields` package at system level:

1. Deactivate virtualenv.
2. pip install def-compound-fields
3. Activate virtualenv and start django process